# Dar formato a dato tipo DECIMAL de MySQL 1,000.00 e insertarlo en la base de datos como 1000.00

Tags: php, mysql

recurro a ustedes por el siguiente problema que se me presenta en un CRUD.
Me gustaría que me echasen una mano y que les agradezco con anticipación.
El asunto es:
Utilizando una función con Javascript yo puedo recuperar de la tabla "PRECIOS" el campo "precio" de tipo DECIMAL(10,2) que me almacena por ejemplo 10000.00 para (Diez Mil dolares). En el input me muestra el siguiente formato: 10,000.00
Ahora bien, cuando quiero insertar ese valor a la base de datos, solo me toma 100.00. Entonces, me gustaría saber que puedo utilizar para que el valor recibido en el input y cuando lo escriba me convierta el numero a valor valido para el tipo de dato DECIMAL de la base de datos.
Ejemplifico a continuación:

Tabla PRECIOS:
Campo: precio DECIMAL(10,2).

CONSULTA:

```
SELECT format(precio,2) FROM precios;
```

Registros en el campo precio: 500000.00 (Con tipo DECIMAL(10,2)
La consulta devuelve: 500,000.00

Hasta aquí todo perfecto, me muestra en el input el valor 500,000.00
Sin embargo, cuando quiero actualizar el campo y ponerle 600,000.00 me lo guarda
como 600.00 y no me guarda 600000.00
Con la funcion javascript el input me muestra 600,000.00 pero no me lo guarda. 
Que necesitaria hacer para poder guardarlo?
De este formato que toma el input con la ayuda de la funcion javascript: 600,000.00 a 600000.00 ?

El codigo usado de javascript:

```
    <script>
  $("#numero").on({
    "focus": function (event) {
      $(event.target).select();
    },
    "keyup": function (event) {
      $(event.target).val(function (index, value ) {
        return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Este es el input:

```
<input id="numero" name="numero" class="form-control input-sm py-2 border-left-0 border" placeholder="0.00" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Entu base de datos el formato debería ser solo uno, en cambio en la vista es donde te debes ocupar de formatear el dato de acuerdo con la salida esperada, por que imagina si tuvieras que almacenar 10 tipos de moneda distinta para ese mismo registro?

Comment: La situacion es que , en el input donde yo ingreso el precio para guardarlo, he utilizado la funcion de javascript para que el usuario lo vea asi:
500,000.00
en vez de verlo asi:
500000.00
El por eso que cuando intento insertarlo, no me lo guarda asi:
500000.00
Solo me toma 500.00
He buscado por muchos lugares con diferentes formas, pero no va ninguna, agradezco sus aportaciones.

Comment: Hola en el mundo hispano usamos "." para miles y "," para decimales; no así en el anglófono que lo hacen al revés. Tu aplicativo depende de los **locales** de quién llene el formulario y tu backend de los definidos dónde esté instalado. Si además puedes tener público de orígenes diversos no puedes hacerlos escribir **como quieras** o **esperas** de modo que debes partir la entrada entre **parte entera** y **céntimos** o decimales y juntar el dato antes de guardar. Así te evitas dolores de cabeza.

Comment: SOLVENTADO!!
Muchas Gracias!
Codigo:  $precio = str_replace(',', '', $_POST["precio"]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solventado, a la hora de enviar por POST el nuevo dato del percio, utilicé la funcion

```
str_replace(',', '.', $variable);
```

Donde reemplacé el '.' por un espacio vacio ''.

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
$precio = str_replace(',', '', $_POST["precio"]);
```